# On the action of $ (H^1(\Omega))^\prime$ on $H^1(\Omega) $, if the element of $ (H^1(\Omega))^\prime$ is in $L^2 (\Omega)$.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations, applications

Let $\Omega$ be any open set in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $(H^1(\Omega))^\prime$ denote the dual of $H^1(\Omega)$. Then do we have the following?
\begin{equation*}
H^1(\Omega) \subset L^2 (\Omega) \subset (H^1(\Omega))^\prime.
\end{equation*}
More specifically, can we say if $f \in L^2 (\Omega)$, then 
\begin{equation*}
<f,v>_{(H^1(\Omega))^\prime, H^1(\Omega)} = \int_\Omega fv \qquad \forall v \in H^1 (\Omega).
\end{equation*}
I know the above identification holds for the triple  $H_0^1(\Omega) \subset L^2 (\Omega) \subset H^{-1}(\Omega)$. But I am unsure about the case for $H^1(\Omega), L^2 (\Omega), (H^1(\Omega))^\prime$.

Comment: How exactly do you know that $H_0^1(\Omega)\subset L^2(\Omega)\subset H^{-1}(\Omega)$?
Does the same reason also work for your question?
If it does not work, where exactly does the first problem occur?

Comment: Yes, the same reason applies for my problem. And we have exactly the same results, specifically $ H^1 (\Omega) \subset L^2 (\Omega) \subset (H^1 (\Omega))^\prime$. Is this ok?

Comment: Sounds good to me.